# Let $\Gamma\subset X$. Is $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the smallest $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ that necessarily contains $\Gamma$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a measurable space and $\Gamma\subseteq X$. Is the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the smallest* $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ that necessarily contains $\Gamma$? I can prove that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\Gamma$, but is there a smaller one?

*By smallest here, I mean is there a set $S\subsetneq\mathcal{P}(X)$ which is both a $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ and contains $\Gamma$?

Comment: The power set of $\Gamma$ is not even a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. For example $X\notin\mathcal P(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Assuming $\Gamma$ is a nonempty strict subset of $X$, the sigma-algebra on $X$ that contains $\Gamma$ and that has the fewest sets is one that contains exactly 4 sets.  Can you find those 4 sets?

Comment: @Michael do you mean $\{\varnothing, \Gamma, X-\Gamma, X\}$?

Comment: Yes.  So, does that answer your question?

Comment: @Michael Yes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For closure, you can provide a formal answer to your own question and then vote it as "best answer."  That is accepted practice when getting an answer based on hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Gamma\subsetneq X$, $\Gamma\neq\varnothing$, then $\Sigma=\{\varnothing,\Gamma,X-\Gamma,X\}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ containing $\Gamma$. This is because $\Gamma\in\Sigma$ implies $X-\Gamma\in\Sigma$ and we always have $\varnothing,X\in\Sigma$.